# How to make response data available outside the function

Tags: node.js, function, http, post

Data received from the server is written into variable `cols`. But it is empty in the output. I'm not sure if `cols` has now a proper value and is available to work with.

```
    app.post('/get_columns', function (req, res, next) {
          var cols = '';
          var httpreq = http.request(options, function (response) {
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
              cols += chunk;
              console.log("body: " + cols);
            });
          });
          httpreq.write(options_data);
          httpreq.end();
          console.log('cols: '+cols);
      });
```

What output shows:

```
cols: 
body: {"ResultSet Output":[{"NAME": "PART_COL1"},{"NAME": "PART_COL2"}],"StatusCode": 200,"StatusDescription": "Execution Successful"}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **HTTP** Calls are asynchronous call in Node.js and the **response comes as multiple chunks through Events**. When you are dealing
>   with HTTP request in Node.js, you have to deal with **"data" & "end"
>   events on the response object** given by HTTP.

### Below examples shows how you can deal with the response in HTTP:

```
app.post('/get_columns', function (req, res, next) {
  var cols = '';
  var httpreq = http.request(options, function (response) {
    // This event is triggered multiple times whenever a chunk is available.
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      cols += chunk;
    });

    // This event is triggered once when all the chunks are completed.
    response.on('end', function (chunk) {
      console.log("body: " + cols);
    });
  });
  httpreq.write(options_data);
  httpreq.end();
});
```

---

**Another organized way to handle**

```
var fetchCols = function (options, options_data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var cols = '';
    var httpreq = http.request(options, function (response) {
      // This event is triggered multiple times whenever a chunk is available.
      response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        cols += chunk;
      });

      // This event is triggered once when all the chunks are completed.
      response.on('end', () => {
        resolve(cols);
      });
    });

    // This event is triggered when there is any error.
    httpreq.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e);
    });
    httpreq.write(options_data);
    httpreq.end();
  });
};

app.post('/get_columns', function (req, res, next) {
  fetchCols(options, options_data)
    .then((cols) => {
      console.log('body: ', cols);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('ERR: ', cols);
    });
});
```